# Lean Winamp-y player for OSX

Tags: macos, music

One of my big gripes about iTunes is that it is slow and eats memory. I really like the old Winamp model of *lean, mean, speed machine*.  Is there such a program for Macs? (I only want an mp3 player with a playlist...don't need anything else really).

Comment: I've seen people seriously advise others to run WinAMP in a VM to save on memory, so... yeah. If it's any help, foobar2000 (basically, as mp3 player with a playlist) works great in wine, and doesn't that have a port in OS X?

Comment: Wow...maybe I should write a MacAmp program. >.<

Comment: @PaulNathan: Um, huh? There *is* a MacAmp program available. I link to it in my answer below. Here's that link again: http://www.macamplite.com/

Comment: It's going on 3 years unupdated, from what I can tell.

Comment: @Paul: And yet it works perfectly well.  It's not necessarily the kind of software that needs a lot of updates. (That is, it isn't constantly adding features.)

Comment: Worth a look for other links: http://superuser.com/questions/12015/favorite-music-player-for-os-x/12678

Answer (score 1):

Try [Vox](http://www.voxapp.uni.cc/)

Comment: Another post mentions that Vox frequently crashes. What's your experience with that? http://superuser.com/questions/12015/favorite-music-player-for-os-x/12678#12678

Comment: I use once or twice a day every time with the same files (I love my music :-) ) and never had a crash. Maybe some strange format ?

Answer (score 0):

There is still a [MacAmpLite](http://www.macamplite.com/) available.

Having said that, if you want *really* light and you're at all into the terminal, look into [`cmus`](http://cmus.sourceforge.net/). It's a great ncurses-based, command-line music player, available through [MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/audio/cmus/Portfile).

Comment: I like cmus. Except for the whole vi-interface concept(appropriately undocumented on the homepage).... *sighs*.

Comment: @Paul: Maybe that's why I like it so much, as I'm already a Vim user and vi-mode Bash user (not to mention mutt, less and on and on).

Answer (score 0):

Might want to have a look at [Cog](http://www.cogx.org/). (Also see [a post](https://superuser.com/questions/12015/favorite-music-player-for-os-x/91367#91367) about its pros and cons.)